# How to give rounded corners to a linear layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable, android-constraintlayout

**I want to overlay my `LinearLayout` with rounded corners on top of `ImageView` but there is still white color in background. How to remove that?**

[image]

#### activity_main

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/mountains" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/linear_layout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-medium"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:text="@string/the_white_mountains"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

#### linear_layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/black"/>
    <corners android:topLeftRadius="15dp" android:topRightRadius="15dp"/>
</shape>
```

How do I remove those white corners?

Comment: In your case default background colour for ConstraintLayout is white. You can change to desired colour using -> Example: android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"

Answer (score 0):

Your drawable is fine, but you need to adjust the constraints as the `ImageView` doesn't take the entire height of the screen, and so that it doesn't really intersect with the `LinearLayout`.

So, add the `ImageView` bottom constraints to parent not to the top of the `LinearLayout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/mountains" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/linear_layout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-medium"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:text="@string/the_white_mountains"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Preview

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This white color in the background is the default background color of the Constraintlayout. if you want to change it, add this attribute to your  Constraintlayout:

```
android:background="#E53935"
```

it will look like  this:
[image]

as you can see the background color has changed but since there is no empty space between widgets we can only see the color on the top corners.
if this ImageView is static you can set the background color as the bottom image color, which is :#1E1D2D

it will look like  this:
[image]

if this ImageView is not static you can make some space between widgets like this for example:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/mountains" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:background="@drawable/linear_layout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-medium"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:text="@string/the_white_mountains"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

it will look like  this:

[image]

I hope my explanation is clear and useful.